# How to make value text in form be italic

Tags: css

I have a script that erases the default value text in the form when the user clicks in the field, but how can I make the value text appear in italics? If I change the input in my css to font-style:italic then when the user types it appears in italics too and I just want the "preview text" to be in italics and then normal when the user is typing.

http://tylerbrockphotography.com/contact1.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a different selector for each engine, unfortunately.

```css
#box::-webkit-input-placeholder { font-style: italic; }
#box::-ms-input-placeholder { font-style: italic; }
#box::-moz-placeholder { font-style: italic; }
```

[Here’s a demo!](http://dabblet.com/gist/8d934e341cef239dbb7a)