# Italic text inside echo in php html

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to itlic the text inside a Php condition but it's not working as it displays the tags instead of applying it. And I only want the `Text to be italic` to be italic, but if the other value was true `$this->input->getinput()` then no italic needed.

```
<input
        type="text" required
        class= "form-control"
        id   = "id"
        name = "name"
        value= "<?php echo (!empty($this->input->getinput()))?  $this->input->getinput(): '<a style="text-align: center"><i>Text to be italic</i></a>'?>"
        title = "title"
/>
```

Comment: is it right that you have double double $ in $$this->input->getinput()?

Comment: @f_anto edited, sorry. But it still doesn't work

Comment: did you take any error ?

Comment: @IvanBarayev nope, it just displays the tags instead of applying their effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use styles into value sub tags

Please try below code

```
<input
        type="text" required
        class= "form-control"
        id   = "id"
        name = "name"
        <?php echo (!empty($this->input->getinput())) ?  ' value="'.$this->input->getinput().'" ' : ' style="font-style: italic" value="Text to be italic" '; ?>
        title = "title"
/>
```

Comment: I only want the `Text to be italic` to be italic, but if the other value was true `$this->input->getinput()` then no italic needed.

Comment: I've done that but now the text `title = "title" />` appears as a value afterwards

Comment: write here complete line of input

Comment: Don't worry, I figured it out, your answer is correct thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You are **not allowed** to make some tag eg. `<i>some text</i>` inside value attribut. You want it

`<input type="text" value="<a style="text-align: center"><i>Text to be italic</i></a>">`

,isn't it?
But there is way to make it by CSS. Follow this [How to make value text in form be italic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291925/how-to-make-value-text-in-form-be-italic).

Or this another reference [HTML in the input field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823835/html-in-the-input-field-value)